# Limit ArcTanh: different results in v10.4 and v11.3

Tags: calculus-and-analysis

I find a different results when computing limits with ArcTanh in version 10 and 11 of Mathematica.

The problem emerges with the following function

```
foo[a_, b_] := ArcTanh[a + I b] + ArcTanh[-a + I b]

{ Limit[ foo[a, b], b -> 0, Direction -> -1, Assumptions -> {a > 0} ]
 , Limit[ foo[a, b], b -> 0, Direction -> -1, Assumptions -> {a > 1} ]
 , Limit[ foo[a, b], b -> 0, Direction -> 1, Assumptions -> {a > 0} ]
 , Limit[ foo[a, b], b -> 0, Direction -> 1, Assumptions -> {a > 1} ] }
```

In version 10.4, I obtain

```
{0, I \[Pi], 0, -I \[Pi]}
```

while in version 11.3

```
0, 0, 0, 0}
```

Is it possible to reconcile the results?

Best regards

Comment: I'm not saying anything specific about correctness of these results, but isn't it a bit odd if the non-parameterized limit is different for `a > 1` than what it is for `a > 0`...

Comment: Yes it's a bug in MMA `11.3`.Nothing is perfect.

Comment: `Plot[Im@foo[a, 1/100], {a, -2, 2}]` and `Plot[Im@foo[a, -1/100], {a, -2, 2}]` (and similar for `Re` to show result there is zero) indicates that the 10.4 result (which is also the result in the current development builds) is "almost" correct. The cases where the assumption is `a>0` are correct only under the further restriction that `a<1`.

Comment: @kirma your point is relevant, but we should keep in mind that we are considering the limits of an analytically continued function to the complex plane. Note that -1 < Tanh[x] < 1 for real x. Hence, taking limits of its inverse function should always be done with care, specially if going outside of this domain.

Comment: @DanielLichtblau thank you for the info regarding the direction of the development build.
I would say that I am confident that the correct result is that obtained in v10.4
Do you recommend reporting this to Wolfram as bug?

Comment: @fabio.hipolito I suspect it is somewhare in the bugs data base already. Possibly not in this exact form, but at least as a close cousin.

Answer (score 2):

Both the results seem to be incorrect in view of

```
Plot3D[Re[ArcTanh[a + I b]+ArcTanh[-a + I b]],{a, -2, 2},{b, -2, 2},AxesLabel -> Automatic]
```

[image]

```
Plot3D[Im[ArcTanh[a + I b]+ArcTanh[-a + I b]],{a, -2, 2},{b, -2,2}, AxesLabel -> Automatic]
```

[image]

AFAIU, it should be

> {Indeterminate, I [Pi], Indeterminate, -I [Pi]}